# Passing the same method reference to a filter in apache flink throws classcastException

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

The following code throws a ClasscastException (java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class java.lang.String )

```
        final DataStreamSource<String> st1 = environment.fromCollection(List.of("asdf", "asfd"));
        final DataStreamSource<Integer> st2 = environment.fromCollection(List.of(1, 2, 3));
        st1.filter(Objects::nonNull);
        st2.filter(Objects::nonNull);
```

but when provided like this

```
        final DataStreamSource<String> st1 = environment.fromCollection(List.of("asdf", "asfd"));
        final DataStreamSource<Integer> st2 = environment.fromCollection(List.of(1, 2, 3));
        st1.filter(s -> Objects.nonNull(s));
        st2.filter(i -> Objects.nonNull(i));
```

everything works fine.

Bug or Feature?

Flink: 1.17.0, java 11

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.
If you write it this way, it gives you an error.

```java
.filter(Objects::nonNull)
```

and then switching to

```java
.filter(jsonObject -> jsonObject ! = null).
```

and everything is fine.